# POWER plane PCB design

Tags: pcb, design

why we need power plane in PCB design, suppose  i have 6 different supply rails like 1.2v,1.8v, 2.5v, 3.3v and 5v and 12v supply then how much power plane do i need , and how can arrange  them Layer stack up

Comment: please give some suggestion .....your suggestion would be very helpful for me ....thanks

Comment: How many layers have you planned in your PCB?

Comment: Work out the requirements for each supply individually ... some may be low current or only to a few components; these won't usually need a power plane. You may be able to group all the 2.5V components and their regulator together for example. If you're still in doubt, add this info to the question.

Comment: i planned for 12 layer. i need at least 8 layer to route my board bcoz high speed routing is involve in board.@flyerdragon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends totally on where you need the power, how much power and on your power integrity requirements.

I have done things like that on a single plane, or on 4 planes, it just depends on what you are about.

I would note that running a split power plane with a closely coupled high speed signal layer is a bad idea from a return current perspective, so some care is advised, but there is nothing inherently wrong with split (even very split) planes if your part placement works with that.